# Evaluating distance matrix in an efficient way in LEMON library

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, lemon-graph-library

I'm using the [LEMON library](https://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon) in a project of mine and I have a doubt about how to best use it to evaluate a complete distance matrix between vertices in a given set.

So, consider we are given a large graph (represented as a `ListDigraph`), a subset of vertices `S` and we need to evaluate all shortest paths between any two vertices in `S`.

The easiest way to do that would be running the `Dijkstra` algorithm for each combination of two vertices in `S`, but of course this not the best idea in terms of efficiency.

One thing that I thought was to evaluate one path from a vertex i to a vertex j, both in `S`, and then search the `ProcessedMap` for any other vertex in S. If I find one, say k, I already have the distance from i to k. This would most probably reduce the number of calls to the algorithm. However I still think there should be a better solution in lemon.

Is adding multiple sources of any help? I didn't quite understand yet the behaviour of the class `Dijkstra` when using this feature.

Thank you =)

Comment: How dense is the graph?

Comment: One quick improvement over running Dijkstra on all vertex *pairs* is to just run it to completion on all *vertices*: It computes the shortest path from a given vertex to *all* other vertices in (asymptotically) the same time as the shortest path to a given other vertex.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat  ~30k vertices and |S| is ~400. It takes several minutes sometimes if I do in the easiest way

Comment: @j_random_hacker My graph is an OpenStreetMap map and S contains some vertices added into the map later. The thing is that I only need the distances between these vertices in S which are not as much as the vertices on the map. If they are kind of clustered in the same region it would be a waste of time running the algorithm for all vertices

Comment: Ah, if it's a road network, then there are some very efficient shortest path algorithms in the literature specifically designed for it.